# Simplest way to get rbind to ignore column names

Tags: r, rbind

This came up just in an answer to another question here.  When you `rbind` two data frames, it matches columns by name rather than index, which can lead to unexpected behavior:

```
> df<-data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4)
> df
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
> rbind(df,df[,2:1])
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 1 3
4 2 4
```

Of course, there are workarounds.  For example:

```
rbind(df,rename(df[,2:1],names(df)))
data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(df),as.matrix(df[,2:1])))
```

On edit: `rename` from the `plyr` package doesn't actually work this way (although I thought I had it working when I originally wrote this...).  The way to do this by renaming is to use SimonO101's solution:

```
rbind(df,setNames(df[,2:1],names(df)))
```

Also, maybe surprisingly,

```
data.frame(rbindlist(list(df,df[,2:1])))
```

works by index (and if we don't mind a data table, then it's pretty concise), so this is a difference between `do.call(rbind)`.

The question is, what is the most concise way to `rbind` two data frames where the names don't match?  I know this seems trivial, but this kind of thing can end up cluttering code.  And I don't want to have to write a new function called `rbindByIndex`.  Ideally it would be something like `rbind(df,df[,2:1],byIndex=T)`.

Comment: Interesting.  Though personally I'd rather that `rbind` on dataframes take the care to match named subsets (i.e. columns).  When you don't want to "track" things by name, use `matrix` in the first place?

Comment: One (maybe the only) reason not to use `matrix` is because it doesn't allow mixing of types.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You might find `setNames` handy here...

```
rbind(df, setNames(rev(df), names(df)))
#  x y
#1 1 3
#2 2 4
#3 3 1
#4 4 2
```

I suspect your real use-case is somewhat more complex. You can of course reorder columns in the first argument of `setNames` as you wish, just use `names(df)` in the second argument, so that the names of the reordered columns match the original.

Comment: Thanks, I had been using `rename` from the `plyr` package, and now when I try rerunning my code from the OP, it doesn't work.

Comment: @mrip well I hope this is useful for your real use-case!

Comment: @SimonO101 I like the simplicity of the code inside `setNames`.

Comment: This doesn't ignore it, does it? It just sets the names to be the same.

Answer (score 9):

This seems pretty easy:

```
mapply(c,df,df[,2:1])
     x y
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 4
[3,] 3 1
[4,] 4 2
```

For this simple case, though, you have to turn it back into a dataframe (because `mapply` simplifies it to a matrix):

```
as.data.frame(mapply(c,df,df[,2:1]))
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 3 1
4 4 2
```

*Important note 1*: There appears to be a downside of type coercion when your dataframe contains vectors of different types:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:2,y=3:4,z=c('a','b'))
mapply(c,df,df[,c(2:1,3)])
     x y z
[1,] 1 3 2
[2,] 2 4 1
[3,] 3 1 2
[4,] 4 2 1
```

*Important note 2*: It also is terrible if you have factors.

```
df<-data.frame(x=factor(1:2),y=factor(3:4))
mapply(c,df[,1:2],df[,2:1])
     x y
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 1 1
[4,] 2 2
```

So, as long as you have all numeric data, it's okay.

Comment: But you'll get into trouble if you have different data types in the df.

Comment: @Roland Yup, I just edited to that effect. Anyway around that?

Comment: Yes, write an `rbindByIndex` function, which the OP explicitly doesn't want to do ...

Comment: If you don't have factors, you can get this to work with mixed types by `data.frame(mapply(c(df,df[,c(2,1,3)]),SIMPLIFY=F))`, but then it's not as nice and concise.

Comment: Or use `Map` which is `mapply(...,SIMPLIFY=FALSE)` - `data.frame(Map(c,df,df[,2:1]))`