# Merge multiple columns

Tags: r

**MY DATA**
I have a data.frame `Movement` that contains X and Y column with positional data that belongs to a subject `(ID)`. There are 300+ subjects in my dataset, imported in R from a .csv file. The following is a (small) example of my data. 
`X1 <- c(10.83, 11.91, 12.32)`
`Y1 <- c(25.26, 27.81, 27.96)`
`ID1 <- c("John", "John", "John")`
`X2 <- c(14.73, 15.95, 15.97)`
`Y2 <- c(21.29, 22.83, 23.36)`
`ID2 <- c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom")`

**WHAT I WISH FOR IT TO LOOK LIKE**

Merge all the columns into three and have `Movement` be:
`X <- c(10.83, 11.91, 12.32,14.73, 15.95, 15.97)`
`Y <- c(25.26, 27.81, 27.96, 21.29, 22.83, 23.36)`
`ID <- c("John", "John", "John", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom")`

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
Merge and stack, although this combine my `X` and `Y` values into one `Value` which I do not want. I feel it is a simple question but I am stuck, any assistance please?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just treat the first three columns as one data frame, and the last three columns as another, then just `rbind` them? i.e. something like `rbind(Movement[,1:3], Movement[,4:6])`, taking into consideration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297475/simplest-way-to-get-rbind-to-ignore-column-names

Comment: Just to add to Alex's comment, if the names are not the same, change the names of the first 3 columns to match the other 3 columns or viceversa for `rbind` to work. or just use `rbindlist` which will work fine without changing the names. i.e. `library(data.table);  rbindlist(list(Movement[1:3], Movement[4:6]))`

Comment: The data frame is imported as a .csv file that contains 300+ subjects and their X and Y data so it would be a very long process to do it this way. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are 300+ columns, one option is to get the index of 'ID', 'X', and 'Y' columns using `grep`, unlist the subset of the dataset and create the three columns using the `data.frame`.

```
IndID <-  grep('^ID', names(Movement))
IndX <-   grep('^X', names(Movement))
IndY <-    grep('^Y', names(Movement))

res <-  data.frame(ID=unlist(Movement[IndID]), 
         X=unlist(Movement[IndX]), 
         Y=unlist(Movement[IndY]), 
            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
row.names(res) <- NULL 
res
#    ID     X     Y
#1 John 10.83 25.26
#2 John 11.91 27.81
#3 John 12.32 27.96
#4  Tom 14.73 21.29
#5  Tom 15.95 22.83
#6  Tom 15.97 23.36
```

Or you could use `melt` from the `devel` version of `data.table` (i.e. v.1.9.5).  It can be installed from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
melt(setDT(Movement), measure=list(IndX, IndY, IndID),
     value.name=c('X', 'Y', 'ID'))[,variable:= NULL][]
#      X     Y   ID
#1: 10.83 25.26 John
#2: 11.91 27.81 John
#3: 12.32 27.96 John
#4: 14.73 21.29  Tom
#5: 15.95 22.83  Tom
#6: 15.97 23.36  Tom
```

Or  `merged.stack` from `splitstackshape`.

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 library(data.table)
 merged.stack(setDT(Movement, keep.rownames=TRUE),
     var.stubs=c('X', 'Y', 'ID'), sep='var.stubs')[, 1:2 := NULL][] 
 #      X     Y   ID
 #1: 10.83 25.26 John
 #2: 14.73 21.29  Tom
 #3: 11.91 27.81 John
 #4: 15.95 22.83  Tom
 #5: 12.32 27.96 John
 #6: 15.97 23.36  Tom
```

#### data

```
Movement <- structure(list(X1 = c(10.83, 11.91, 12.32), Y1 = c(25.26,
27.81, 27.96), ID1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "John",
class = "factor"), 
X2 = c(14.73, 15.95, 15.97), Y2 = c(21.29, 22.83, 23.36), 
ID2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Tom", class = "factor")),
.Names = c("X1",  
"Y1", "ID1", "X2", "Y2", "ID2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L),
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Excellent, I successfully used `grep` to easily create the data frame. Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, do all columns need to be of the same row length?

Comment: @user2716568 If you need a `data.frame`, the columns should be of the same length.  If it is not, you can store in a `list`.  I am not sure I understand you properly.  This question was asked some time back.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes, a `data.frame` is what I am after. Currently, I am using your `grep` and `data.frame` example to compile a new dataset that is structured in the same manner as above (same column headers, multiple columns). The code is not working and it may be because there are a different number of rows for each entry. I can open this as a new question, if you consider appropriate.

Comment: @user2716568  It would be better to open as a new question with the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Using both my comment and Akrun's

```
library(data.table)

Movement <- data.frame(X1 = c(10.83, 11.91, 12.32),
                       Y1 = c(25.26, 27.81, 27.96),
                       ID1 = c("John", "John", "John"), 
                       X2 = c(14.73, 15.95, 15.97), 
                       Y2 = c(21.29, 22.83, 23.36), 
                       ID2 = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom"))

rbindlist(list(Movement[,1:3], Movement[,4:6]))
```

gives

```
      X1    Y1  ID1
1: 10.83 25.26 John
2: 11.91 27.81 John
3: 12.32 27.96 John
4: 14.73 21.29  Tom
5: 15.95 22.83  Tom
6: 15.97 23.36  Tom
```

It is easy enough to then rename the columns to be what you want.

Assuming that movement consists of 100 triplets `(Xn, Yn, IDn)`, then an intermediate step is to construct a list of individual data frames. You can do this using

```
list_of_df <- lapply(1:100, function(j) Movement[,(3*j-2):(3*j)])
```

Then, `rbindlist(list_of_df)`

Answer (score 1):

Either of these would succeed:

```
> reshape(Moment, direction="long",  sep="", varying=list("X"=c(1,4),"Y"=c(2,5),"ID"=c(3,6)))
    PT time    X1    Y1  ID1 id
1.1  1    1 10.83 25.26 John  1
2.1  2    1 11.91 27.81 John  2
3.1  3    1 12.32 27.96 John  3
4.1  4    1 10.83 25.26 John  4
5.1  5    1 11.91 27.81 John  5
6.1  6    1 12.32 27.96 John  6
1.2  1    2 14.73 21.29  Tom  1
2.2  2    2 15.95 22.83  Tom  2
3.2  3    2 15.97 23.36  Tom  3
4.2  4    2 14.73 21.29  Tom  4
5.2  5    2 15.95 22.83  Tom  5
6.2  6    2 15.97 23.36  Tom  6

> reshape(Moment, direction="long",  sep="", varying=1:6, v.names=c("X","Y","ID"))
    PT time    X     Y    ID id
1.1  1    1 John 10.83 25.26  1
2.1  2    1 John 11.91 27.81  2
3.1  3    1 John 12.32 27.96  3
4.1  4    1 John 10.83 25.26  4
5.1  5    1 John 11.91 27.81  5
6.1  6    1 John 12.32 27.96  6
1.2  1    2  Tom 14.73 21.29  1
2.2  2    2  Tom 15.95 22.83  2
3.2  3    2  Tom 15.97 23.36  3
4.2  4    2  Tom 14.73 21.29  4
5.2  5    2  Tom 15.95 22.83  5
6.2  6    2  Tom 15.97 23.36  6
```

(I had put an id-variable in my test opbject but it wasn't needed:

```
Moment <- data.frame(X1 = c(10.83, 11.91, 12.32),
Y1  =c(25.26, 27.81, 27.96),
ID1= c("John", "John", "John"),
X2 =c(14.73, 15.95, 15.97),
Y2 = c(21.29, 22.83, 23.36),
ID2 = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom") )

reshape(Moment, direction="long",  sep="", varying=1:6, v.names=c("X","Y","ID"))
    time    X     Y    ID id
1.1    1 John 10.83 25.26  1
2.1    1 John 11.91 27.81  2
3.1    1 John 12.32 27.96  3
1.2    2  Tom 14.73 21.29  1
2.2    2  Tom 15.95 22.83  2
3.2    2  Tom 15.97 23.36  3
```