# How to create data.frame from appended columns of other data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very basic problem.
I have a two data frames. 
The first `df1` has 3 columns named `col1` and `col2`

The second `df2` has the columns named `col3` and `col4`and `col5`

I want to create a third data frame with two columns named **Attribute** and **Value** in such a way that *Attribute* is made of the appended value `df1$col1` and `df2$col3` 
*value* is made of the appended values of `df1$col2` and `df2$col4`

**Update:**

I don't actually the same number of columns for `df1` and `df2`. Notice that I ignored `col5` of `df2` ( which is irrelevant for my code)
This means that

```
colnames(df1) <- colnames(df2) <- c("attribute", "value")
rbind.data.frame(df1, df2)
```

is not working for me.

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: No I don't wont to concatenate the column. I want to append the second at the bottom of the second

Comment: Or [Simplest way to get rbind to ignore column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297475/simplest-way-to-get-rbind-to-ignore-column-names)

Comment: sorry, I didn't show on the question for the sake of simplicity but I actually have different number of columns for `df1` and `df2`

Answer (score 0):

`df.n <-NULL
df.n$a<-rbind(df1$col1, df2$col3) 
df.n$b<-rbind(df1$col2,df2$col4)`

This requires that col1+col3 has the same number of rows as col2+col4

Comment: Error: unexpected numeric constant in "df.n$1"

Comment: sorry colnames cannot be numbers I edited

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append `df2` to `df1` the data frames need to have the same columns names.

Otherwise R will complain that the names do not match. Therefore, you have to make the column names the same.

You can achieve this by using the third statement in the following snipped.
Then you can simply `rbind` them to create `df3`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=1, col2=2)
df2 <- data.frame(col3=1, col2=4) 

colnames(df2) <- colnames(df1)

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

Comment: my columns have different names

Comment: @communitywiki that's why I use the colname statement. df3 will have - in this case - column names col1 and col2.

Comment: I am sorry I corrected my question.  I didn't show on the question for the sake of simplicity but I actually have different number of columns for df1 and df2

Comment: @communitywiki then you might have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns