# Combing two dataframes based on matching strings in multiple columns

Tags: r, pattern-matching, string-matching, rbind, cbind

Say I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, that look like this:

```
student     x    y    teacher   value
s.name1     4    5    t.name1   1
s.name2     3    3    t.name1   2
s.name2     2    1    t.name2   3
s.name3     5    5    t.name3   1
```

and that I would like to combine these two dataframes based on the contents of df$student, df$x, df$y, and df$teacher being the same, but NOT df$value. What is the best approach for this? Thanks.

Edit: Figured it out using merge(), posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `rbind`. This has been answered in [Simplest way to get rbind to ignore column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297475/simplest-way-to-get-rbind-to-ignore-column-names). Just use

```
rbind(db1, setNames(rev(db2), names(db1)))
```

In case names are different.

Comment: Both dataframes have the same column names. What if I only want to match based on a subset of the columns in each dataframe, but include other columns which may have different contents?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
merged.df <- merge(df1, df2 ,by=c("student", "teacher", "x", "y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you exactly want to achieve.

Example

`df1 <- data.frame(student = c("A", "B", "C"), teacher = c("Mike", "Leslie", "David"), score = c(80, 90, 100))`

`df2 <- data.frame(student = c("A", "B", "D", "E", "F"), score = c(100, 80, 90, 100, 75), teacher = c("Mike", "Leslie", "Mike", "Leslie", "Bill"))`

`data <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c("student", "teacher"))`

There are many ways to do achieve different results. You can try `merge()`, too.

A page to consult https://rpubs.com/williamsurles/293454