# how to change column name in several data frame in the same time?

Tags: r

I have five data frames which have same number of columns. I want to use `rbind` to append my data, but they have different variable names. Fortunately, it has same form like this.

```
date prod1 code1 tot1

date prod2 code2 tot2

...

date prod5 code5 tot5
```

I want to delete the number-code at the same time, so then I can rbind my data frames. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297475/simplest-way-to-get-rbind-to-ignore-column-names

Comment: If you put them in a list you can `lapply` to change the names, but if you are just trying to `rbind` them you can use `data.table::rbindlist(list(df, df2), use.names = F)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `magrittr` and `dplyr` :

```r
d1 <- mtcars
d2 <- d1
d3 <- d1

names(d2) <- paste0(names(d2), "_2")
names(d3) <- paste0(names(d2), "_3")

rbind(d1, d2, d3) # gives an error, ok
#> Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)): les noms ne correspondent pas aux noms précédents

library(magrittr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df_list <- list(d2, d3)
df_list <- lapply(df_list, magrittr::set_colnames, names(d1))

df_final <- rbind(d1, dplyr::bind_rows(df_list) )
nrow(df_final) == 3* nrow(d1)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the questions was how to change the column names, I will address this problem first:

```
lapply(dflist, setNames, nm = new_col_name)

df1 <- data.frame(prod1 = 1:5, code1 = 1:5, tot1 = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(prod2 = 1:5, code2 = 1:5, tot2 = 1:5)

dflist <- list(df1, df2)

lapply(dflist, setNames, nm = c("prod", "code", "tot"))

[[1]]
   prod code tot
1     1    1   1
2     2    2   2
3     3    3   3
4     4    4   4
5     5    5   5


[[2]]
   prod code tot
1     1    1   1
2     2    2   2
3     3    3   3
4     4    4   4
5     5    5   5
```

As already mentioned it may be better just to ignore column names and use `rbindlist` from `data.table` to bind rows.

```
data.table::rbindlist(dflist, use.names = F)
```

Comment: for example, if the name of every data frame is produk1, produk2,... produk 5, then i have to do rbind like this "rbindlist(produk1,produk2,produk3,produk4,produk5, use.names = F)"?

Comment: you could also do this: ```dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(dflist, setNames, nm = c("prod", "code", "tot")))```. This would rename and then rbind all rows. However, data.table is the better solution. If the answer was helpful, please do not forgot to accept it :-)

Comment: rbindlist rbinds a list. So you have to write it like this: 

```rbindlist(list(produk1,produk2,produk3,produk4,produk5), use.names = F)```. Do not forget the list function.